# Uploading image into a db and folder

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem i've created a code for uploading text and image into a database and a folder. Few days back I was wondering how to create a unique id and to be inserted. I've figured it out a way but then the code doesn't upload the image into the database only into the folder.

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO image_area2
                ('id',`name`,`path`,`unique_id`)
            VALUES
                ('','$file_name','uploads/$file_name','$_POST[un_id]');
        ";
```

The code seems to be fine for the image to be insert into the database but it doesn't work and I can't figure it out. Thank you for the help in advance.

My answears so far so you could see it better:

- Well the problem is i don't have any error which is the strangest thing. It works perfectly it inserts the text into the db and the image into the folder but it doesn't insert the path and name into the db. And the code for the insertion is ok i think and i can't figure it why it doesn't do it. I've used print_r($query) function to see if the code is receiving the information from the form and it is receiving it.
- Well i've added the mysql_query($query); row and nothing again it has added the text into the db and the image into the folder but nothig about the image into the db. $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] i use it to define and get the name,tmp name size and type and i've put them into the array $file_name,$file_size,$file_type and $file_tmp
- Well i've cleared the id it posted one time but the strange thing is that i've added 1 image and in the db there where 2 lines for the same image and then if i want to add new text and new image again it doesn't work 1 or more images are added into the folder only.

RESOLVED:
The problem was resolved with 2 steps the one that i was written 'id' like that and it wasn't needed anyway and the second the WAMP server was having problems and it was removed and changed. Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "The insert doesn't work" ? Give us SQL errors or wanted inputs VS current input

Comment: do you run $query string in mysql_query function?

Comment: I believe you are trying to store the `path`to the database and the image to the folder.Also,if you want to actually store the image,you need to have your datatypes set to BLOB,CLOB kinds.But in real its not a good practice to store images in DB.If you have any errors for mysql queries,edit the post with specifics so others can help better

Comment: Please add details, otherwise please answer comments, how do you expect someone to help you if you are not willing to help yourself?

Comment: Try echoing your $query to see what is actually being inserted.  Try running that through phpmyadmin and see what errors if any occur.

Comment: Well the problem is i don't have any error which is the strangest thing. It works perfectly it inserts the text into the db and the image into the folder but it doesn't insert the path and name into the db. And the code for the insertion is ok i think and i can't figure it why it doesn't do it.
I've used print_r($query) function to see if the code is receiving the information from the form and it is receiving it.

Comment: How about `mysql_query($query);` after your INSERT statement?

Comment: so, did your cat ate the rest of your code or it stops there?

Comment: Well i've added the mysql_query($query); row and nothing again it has added the text into the db and the image into the folder but nothig about the image into the db.
 $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] i use it to define and get the name,tmp name size and type and i've put them into the array $file_name,$file_size,$file_type and $file_tmp

Comment: Most likely your `path` field in your database table either a) doesn't exist; b) isn't a `VARCHAR`; or c) has a length limit which you are exceeding.

Comment: Path is varchar(150) i've change it to 255 but still the same. The table have id,name,path

Answer (score 0):

If your code is copy/pasted from the actual file, your SQL is using the incorect quote marks in the field list. It should be:

```
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO image_area2
            (`id`,`name`,`path`,`unique_id`)
        VALUES
            ('','$file_name','uploads/$file_name','$_POST[un_id]');
    ";
```

(Notice the back-ticks around `id` rather than the normal single quote-marks

If `id` is an auto-incremented primary key then change the SQL to:

```
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO image_area2
            (`name`,`path`,`unique_id`)
        VALUES
            ('$file_name','uploads/$file_name','$_POST[un_id]');
    ";
```

Also, a few pointers:

1. Sanitize your variables. `$_POST['un_id']` is wide open to SQL
   injection
2. Move away from the `mysql_` functions - they're
   deprecated. Move to `mysqli_` or `PDO` equivalents. This will also
   make prepared functions available and remove the need to sanitize
   your data (if used properly)

Comment: Well i've cleared the id it posted one time but the strange thing is that i've added 1 image and in the db there where 2 lines for the same image and then if i want to add new text and new image again it doesn't work 1 or more images are added into the folder only